# Updating files from master branch to feature branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge

I have recently started learning git.
I have two created two branches, 'master' branch and 'branch1'.

I am working on branch1 currently and have created some new files there.
Also, I have created some new, different files on master branch as well.

My goal is to update my branch with the newly created files in the master branch.

I have tried

```
git fetch origin
git checkout branch1
git merge master
```

but it shows

```
Already up to date
```

Comment: Where is the part where you are "working on feature/branch1 currently and have created some new files there"? In the code you gave, the `feature/branch1` branch has no new work on it. That's why it's up to date.

Comment: I have committed and pushed new files to the branch through eclipse, didn't use git bash for that.

Comment: Are you on `master` (which these days is `main` btw.) when you do `git fetch origin`? If not you'll need `git merge origin/master`

Comment: Also, have you confirmed that the files from `main` are not already in your branch?

Answer (score 0):

Git is basically interested only in *commits*. If you create a feature branch off of master but you don't make a *commit* while you're on that branch, the feature branch has no work on it that distinguishes it from master. Basically, the feature branch *is* master.

To do work, edit-add-commit. *Now* Git will have something to work with.

Comment: I have cloned the repository into eclipse, checked out the feature branch, worked on it, committed the changes, pushed it to the branch, and did the same for master, but different files of course

Comment: My answer is based on the limited information you provided in your question. To get a better answer, improve the question.